# System.InvalidOperationException: The store type 'decimal(18,4)' could not be found in the SqlServer provider manifest

Tags: ef-code-first

I am constructing my connection string the following way (with appropriate values for connection parameters).

```
var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    PersistSecurityInfo = false,
    InitialCatalog = "mydatabase",
    UserID = "myuser",
    Password = "mydatabase",
    DataSource = "myserver"
};
var connectionString = builder.ConnectionString;
using (var db = Helper.MakeContext(connectionString)) {
    var carrier = db.Carriers.FirstOrDefault(); // fails here with error
    Console.WriteLine(carrier.Carrier);
}
```

Helper is in a different project

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using ApiForVivtrack3.Entities;
    
public static class Helper
{
    //public  string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    public static ApiDbContext MakeContext(string connectionString)
    {
        var db = new ApiDbContext(connectionString);
        return db;
    }
}
```

The EF 6.2 `DbContext` is set up as follows

```
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace ApiForVivtrack3.Entities
{
    public partial class ApiDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApiDbContext(string efConnectString)
            : base(efConnectString)
        {

        }

        // DbSet declarations
    }
}
```

The call stack is

```
Test method UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw exception: 
System.InvalidOperationException: The store type 'decimal(18,4)' could not be found in the SqlServer provider manifest
    at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderManifestExtensions.GetStoreTypeFromName(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, String name)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.ConfigureColumn(EdmProperty column, EntityType table, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.Configure(EdmProperty column, EntityType table, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride, Boolean fillFromExistingConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Configure>b__3(Tuple`2 pm)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.IEnumerableExtensions.Each[T](IEnumerable`1 ts, Action`1 action)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.Configure(IEnumerable`1 propertyMappings, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride, Boolean fillFromExistingConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.StructuralTypeConfiguration.ConfigurePropertyMappings(IList`1 propertyMappings, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguration.ConfigurePropertyMappings(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, EntityType entityType, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguration.Configure(EntityType entityType, DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.ConfigureEntityTypes(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, ICollection`1 entitySets, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.Configure(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   at UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1() in D:\devnet10\SBD.Common\UnitTestProject2\UnitTest1.cs:line 39
```

I have done a text search for `Decimal(18`, but nothing comes up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I understand this is an OQ.  Seeing as it is unanswered, I'll share what I had to do.

Do a Find (ctrl F) for (18, 4) or what ever the values are in the error message.  Most likely you will find the text strings show up in the Fluent API section of your solution.
In my case, I copied Fluent API code from a CORE application into my EF 6 application.  Core used "HasColumnType()" which is not compatible with EF 6 that uses "HasPrecision()".

Replace "HasColumnType(" with "HasPrecision(" and run the code again...

Comment: Thank you. That sounds right. I can't remember where I had the problem so I am not totally sure.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by another answer, this error can be thrown by Entity Framework 6 if you attempt to configure a decimal column using syntax taken from Entity Framework Core configuration. `HasColumnType("decimal(18,4)")` needs replacing with `HasPrecision(18,4)`.

This is some regex which can be used to replace all instances of this within your code ([regexr demo](https://regexr.com/6e2js)). Replace this:

`\.HasColumnType\("decimal\((\d+),(\d+)\)"\)`

with this:

`.HasPrecision($1, $2)`

I have tested this regex in JetBrains Rider, but be aware that other IDEs may use different regex flavours. Hopefully this should get you started even if you need to modify it.

Comment: Just in case, I added a small change to a regex because of a space between the second number and the comma. `\.HasColumnType\("decimal\((\d+),\s*(\d+)\)"\)`